# need to display char in xslt

Tags: xslt

Hi all
I am using xslt 1.0. I have the char code as FOA7 which has to displayed as a corresponding character. My input is

`<w:sym w:font="Wingdings" w:char="F0A7"/>`

my xslt template is

```
<xsl:template match="w:sym">
    <xsl:variable name="char" select="@w:char"/>
    <span font-family="{@w:fonts}">        
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x',$char,';')"/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

It showing the error as ERROR:  `'A decimal representation must immediately follow the "&#" in a character reference.'`

Please help me in fixing this..Thanks in advance...

Comment: See my answer, how you __can__ do it, and @Eamon Nerbonne's answer, why you __shouldn't__ do it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in (reasonable) XSLT.  You can work around it.

- Your solution with `concat` is invalid: XSLT is not just a fancy string-concatenator, it really transforms the conceptual *tree*.  An encoded character such as `&#xf0a7;` is a single character - if you were to somehow include the letters `&` `#` `x` `f` `0` `a` `7` `;` then the XSLT processor would be required to include these letters in the XML *data* - not the string!  So that means it will escape them.
- There's no feature in XSLT 1.0 that permits converting from a number to a character with that codepoint.
- In XSLT 2.0, as Michael Kay points out, you can use `codepoints-to-string()` to achieve this.

There are two solutions.  Firstly, you could use `disable-output-escaping`.  This is rather nasty and **not portable**.  Avoid this at all costs if you can - but it will probably work in your transformer, and it's probably the only general, simple solution, so you may not be able to avoid this.

The second solution would be to hardcode matches for each individual character.  That's a mess generally, but quite possible if you're dealing with a limited set of possibilities - that depends on your specific problem.

Finally, I'd recommend *not* solving this problem in XSLT - this is typically something you can do in pre/post processing in another programming environment more appropriately.  Most likely, you've an in-memory representation of the XML document to be able to use XSLT in the first place, in which case this won't even take much CPU time.

Comment: +1. I agree, although the solution seems simple, consequences can be very hard. This question would never happen if an XML design was good.

Comment: Earmon Nerbonne: You wrote *"This isn't possible in (reasonable) XSLT"*. That's wrong, as Dr. Michael Kay has answered there is [codepoints-to-string()](http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#codepoints-to-string) XPath/XSLT 2.0 function

Comment: As you may have overlooked, I referred to the XSLT 2.0 options as one of the bullet points.

Answer (score 2):

```
<span font-family="{@w:font}">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;#x', @w:char, ';')" 
        disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</span>
```

Though check @Eamon Nerbonne's answer, why you shouldn't do it at all.

Comment: yeah; in this *specific* instance this may be the only way to go, but it's not at all ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using XSLT 2.0 (which you aren't), you could write a function to convert hex to decimal, and then use codepoints-to-string() on the result.

Comment: +1 General correct answer. Nothing prevents the update to XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Alejandro. That's rather complex to explain. In short, consider the amount of non-java 2.0 implementations.

Comment: @Flack: There are implementations for .Net platform.

Comment: @Alejandro. Yes, and one written in Eiffel :)

Comment: @Alejandro: which .NET implementation are you referring to?  And note that XSLT is supported in all major browsers (IIRC even in iOS phones), but only version 1.0 is - not 2.0.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne: [Altova](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) has .NET interface, [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/) and [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.3HE), of course.

Comment: Which do you use?  XQSharp is closed-source and costs money (which would be OK if I really needed it, but I'm not likely to bother investing time in something with such limitation unless I need to).  Altova isn't managed, though comes with a managed interface; in my experience that's OK but not ideal (asking for deployment hassles and trickier to debug).   Saxon looks neat; it is however huge - is it still based on IKVM?  That'd probably be my pick, although the limitations sound unhandy; I'll need to bother distinguishing supported from unsupported features.

Comment: Basically, XSLT 2.0 support isn't pervasive enough to be worthwhile unless you intend to really leverage it heavily.  There's the learning curve, the fact that it's not nearly as broadly supported as 1.0, and the limited choice in implementation: great tech, mediocre ecosystem.  I just don't think it's *enough* better than XSLT 1.0 to be worth the costs.

Answer (score 0):

use '&amp;' for '&' in output:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;#x',$char,';')"/>
```

Comment: This would be displayed as `&#xF0A7` in a browser.